# Múltiplos arquivos config em projetos diferentes ASPNET MVC

Tags: c#, .net

Estou com um problema e talvez alguém possa me ajudar.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto `ASPNET MVC` de modo que estruturei a solução em vários projetos para decompor os diferentes componentes.

Em meu arquivo web.config do projeto principal (por exemplo `PROJETO1.Principal`) eu estou tentando configurar para buscar as referências da `connection` strings do projeto geral (por exemplo `PROJETO.Geral`), nesse projeto geral em tenho os arquivo `app.config` que contem minhas `connections` strings.

O código do geral.config está mais ou menos assim:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="app.config"></connectionStrings>
```

Em meu código `app.config` está assim:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<connectionStrings>`
(lista minhas connections strings)`  
</connectionStrings>
```

Porém não funciona, ocorrendo o erro abaixo:

> Não foi possível abrir o arquivo configSource 'app.config'.

Tentei especificar o caminho do arquivo, ocorre o erro abaixo:
O atributo `configSource` deve ser um caminho físico relativo.

Vale frisar que o erro ocorre no ponto que tento abrir a lista de `connections` utilizando `ConfigurationManager` (tentei também com o `WebConfigurationManager` mas sem sucesso).

Outra coisa, se o arquivo `app.config` estivesse dentro do mesmo projeto ele funcionaria sem problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu achei a resposta (vou postar aqui caso mais alguém tenha esse problema).

Eu recriei o arquivo no projeto principal, utilizando "add existing item" e criei como link.

Utilizei essa referência: http://raghurana.com/blog/?p=202

Obrigado

Comment: O ideal é você colocar o texto da referência de forma resumida diretamente no Stackoverflow de forma que uma pessoa que leia possa resolver um problema parecido, assim evita o acesso a outro link, pois o link pode deixar de existir.